# How to correct a RotatedRect skew with OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, android

I wrote an Android application using Opencv , my image processing algorithm needs a correct rotation for my detected rectangle, so as a beginning of the process, I

1. detect the biggest rectangle as a `RotatedRect`.
2. get the rotation angle and the center of the rect.
3. create a rotation matrix with `getRotationMatrix2D`
4. perform the affine transformation using `warpAffine`
5. Extract the detected rectangle using `getRectSubPix`

The hole process is working fine, but I have a problem with the object skew.

When the object is rotated counterclockwise,the skew correction is working great, **but** if it's rotated clockwise the rectangle is rotated 90 degrees.

I need to mention that because the Opencv camera have a wrong orientation, I add -90 to the rectangle rotation angle at first.

Here is my code

```
         /* *******************************************************************************************
         * get angle and size from the rotated rect
         *******************************************************************************************/
        double rect_angle = rbox.angle - 90.0;
        Size rect_size = rbox.size;

        /* *******************************************************************************************
         * correct the orientation 
         *******************************************************************************************/
        double d = rect_size.width;
        rect_size.width = rect_size.height;
        rect_size.height = d;

        M = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(rbox.center, rect_angle, 1.0);
        Imgproc.warpAffine(origMat, rotated, M, origMat.size());

        /* *******************************************************************************************
         * crop the resulting image
         *******************************************************************************************/
        if (rect_size.width > 75 && rect_size.height > 75)
            Imgproc.getRectSubPix(rotated, new Size(rect_size.width - 75, rect_size.height - 75), rbox.center, rotated);

        /* *******************************************************************************************
         * resize the result image because rotated has the size of the rect not the original image
         * which cause the preview camera to be black because of wrong dimensions
         *******************************************************************************************/
        Imgproc.resize(rotated, rotated, origMat.size());
```

Here is a result image when the object is rotated clockwise

[image]

And here is the result image with object rotated counterclockwise

[image]

And here is the original image

[image]

**I should mention** that when the object isn't rotated the angle is -90
and if it's rotated clockwise the angle tends to -179 and if it's rotated counterclockwise the angle become -179 and tends to -90.

I tried to set condition like this

```
if (rbox.angle < -90.0) {
  rect_angle -= 90.0;
}
```

But nothing is working.

I know it's a matter of mathematics but I can't find a way to achieve it, I wish you guys can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone concerned about the answer, I found a solution.

I worked on the width and height of the detected rectangle instead of the angle.

So before creating the rotation matrix i added this test code

```
if (rbox.size.width < rbox.size.height) {
         rect_angle += 90.0;
         double d1 = rect_size.height;
         rect_size.height = rect_size.width;
         rect_size.width = d1;
}
```